# Invalid object name '@ImageIDsToDelete'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is wrong with the following ?

```
DECLARE @ImageIDsToDelete TABLE ( xID INT, ImageID NVARCHAR(500))
INSERT INTO  [@ImageIDsToDelete] (xID, ImageID) SELECT 1,'x'
```

Comment: Looks like I need new glasses 
        DECLARE @ImageIDsToDelete TABLE ( xID INT, ImageID NVARCHAR(500))
  INSERT INTO  @ImageIDsToDelete (xID, ImageID) SELECT 1,'x'

remove [ ]...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with it (after you remove the [])